# Function to return valid date from varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

We have a function that pulls the date from the first 8 characters of a string.  Because of the way this system was written, the users are told they have to enter the date in an 8 character format in the field.  For example, 12/06/10 must be entered.  The way the original function was written, 12/6/10 or 12/06/2010 would generate a wrong date.

I modified the function to the code below to correct this issue and wonder if anyone has any other suggestions to make this more bullet proof.  I'm assuming that returning the datetime will always return a valid date for both 19xx or 20xx.  I'm not sure what SQL uses to determine when to use 19xx vs. 20xx and I'm not worried about dates less that 1980 and greater than 2100.

We are still on SQL Server 2000 for this app.

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDateFromField] ( @FieldString varchar(256) )   
RETURNS datetime AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @tempResult varchar(8)

    SET @tempResult =  left(@FieldString,8)

    IF isdate(@tempResult) = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @tempResult = NULL
    END

    RETURN @tempResult

END
```

Comment: This is better managed in the code that feeds the database -- most modern languages have a function or two that tries to make sense out of whatever the user has entered.

Comment: I agree that the long term solution is to not require the user to enter a date in the first 8 characters.  This should be seperate fields.  Thanks.

Comment: varchar(8) seems a bit overly restrictive - what if your user enters '02/26/2010' ?? Shouldn't that be recognized as a valid date ??

Comment: I agree and this should be changed for the future.  This is a third party app with some custom code.  I'm making some suggestions for the future, but just stepped in to help resolve this issue because the users couldn't access this part of the system because they entered a date of 12/6/10 vs. 12/06/10.  Crazy and not well thought out.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "century cut-off" date is controlled by a SQL Server setting - check out this [blog post](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLDateTimeCutOff.aspx) for a great explanation.

Execute this to see your current setting:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE

sp_configure 'two digit year cutoff'
```

You can also change this option as needed.

Comment: The above code actually changes these setting, not just display them.  I'll check out the blog to learn more.

Thanks.

Comment: @Iceman: no, the above code enables the advanced options, so that you'll actually **see** the "two digit year cutoff" date. It does **NOT** alter that value !!

Comment: @Iceman: only when you issue a command such as `sp_configure 'two digit year cutoff', 2069   reconfigure` will the settings actually be modified....

Answer (score 1):

You could use TRY and CATCH statements to increase robustness.

Comment: Can you use try catch in SQL 2000?

Comment: No, those are SQL Server **2005** and up only

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see the SQL Server 2000 tag when I added my answer.  You'll need to use @@ERROR in SQL Server 2000 for error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Only semi-tested on SQL2000 but I think this handles most date-like input.

```
Alter Function GetDateFromField (
    @FieldString Varchar(256) 
) Returns Datetime 
As 
 Begin 
   Declare @tempResult Char(8), @tempDate as datetime
   If Isdate(@FieldString) = 0
      Set @tempResult = NULL
   Else
    Begin
      Select @tempDate = @FieldString
      Select @tempResult = Convert(Char(8), @tempDate, 1)
   End

   Return @tempResult
End
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing, except I don't convert the date.  It converts it because I'm returning a datetime field.